# :r command works fine until I move it into a IF or BEGIN TRY/END TRY statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

iam facing problem while running files through `SQLCMD`  where i have to do file execution based on conditions

in single run i want to call multiple files(:r) based on conditions

Example :

```
IF 1 =(SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM $(varMasterDB).charts.[UPGRADE_MESSAGE] WHERE pkg='v1.8.103.0')
SET NOEXEC ON;

:r "_1x-Main_Top_Script.sql"

SET NOEXEC OFF;
IF 1 =(SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM $(varMasterDB).charts.[UPGRADE_MESSAGE] WHERE pkg='v1.8.103.0')
SET NOEXEC ON;

:r "_1x-Build9_Top_Script.sql"

SET NOEXEC OFF;
IF 1 =(SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM $(varMasterDB).charts.[UPGRADE_MESSAGE] WHERE pkg='v1.8.103.0')
SET NOEXEC ON;

:r "_1x-Build10_Top_Script.sql"

SET NOEXEC OFF;
IF 1 =(SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM $(varMasterDB).charts.[UPGRADE_MESSAGE] WHERE pkg='v1.8.103.0')
SET NOEXEC ON;
```

---

Here my expectation is  i don 't want to use `SET NOEXEC ON`; i want to skip entire calling file

Comment: You can't do that. `sqlcmd`'s script language and T-SQL are completely separate languages, and you cannot have `sqlcmd` commands executing based on results acquired at runtime. If you want that, you need something more sophisticated, like a batch file.

Comment: maybe you are just missing `BEGIN` and `END`? but from the description at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#sqlcmd-commands it seems that `:r` is more an "include" rather than a "run".

Comment: @devio tried with  BEGIN and END not working .............